Unable to get websocket server connection
Good day to you all, I have just deployed a NodeJs websocket server on Digital ocean platform. it deployed without errors. and logged as expected ... server running on port ####
However, trying to test it from various platforms yield different errors, and Im not sure how to handle each:
locally, the server runs well, only an error about SCP,particulary the nonce error, but, when deployed, it fails completely
first, I wrote a simple frontend script:
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://evse.mydomain.com/'); 
socket.on('open', () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection established');
  socket.send('Hello, server!');
});

socket.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log('Message from server:', data);
});

socket.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
});

socket.on('close', () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
});

running the script via node index.js, i get the error below in the console:
WebSocket error: Error: write EPROTO C0FC699B93720000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 40

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:95:16) {
  errno: -71,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
WebSocket connection closed

I tried using the browser console using the line const ws = new WebSocket('wss://evse.evzone.app'); and I got this error VM102:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://evse.evzone.app/' failed:  (anonymous) @   VM102:1
